# Migration to Wicket 7 - js generated components ajax issues

Tags: ajax, migration, wicket

I'm trying to migrate our application from Wicket 6.19 to Wicket 7. Everything works fine except custom dynamic components generated by javascript libraries - ajax behaviors on these components are not working on Wicket 7.

Example: we have searchable dropdown from bootstrap:

```
public class SearchableDropDown<T> extends DropDownChoice<T> {
...
@Override
public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
    String jqScript = "  $('#" + getMarkupId() + "').select2();";
    response.render(OnDomReadyHeaderItem.forScript(jqScript));
}
...
```

}

And then usage with ajax change listener:

```
SearchableDropDownChoice<String> choice= new SearchableDropDownChoice("choice", model);

choice.setNullValid(true);

choice.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("change") {

        @Override
        protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            // DO SOMETHING
        }
    });
```

This works good with Wicket 6, but Wicket 7 never calls onUpdate. I looked into generated callback javascript on pages ad it looks similar

Wicket 6:

```
Wicket.Ajax.ajax({"c":"choice76","ad":true,"u":"./page?14-2.IBehaviorListener.0-pageStyleClassWrapperPanel-choicePanel-content-choice","e":"change","m":"POST"});;
Wicket.Ajax.ajax({"c":"choice76","ad":true,"u":"./page?14-2.IBehaviorListener.1-pageStyleClassWrapperPanel-choicePanel-content-choice","e":"blur","m":"POST"});;
```

Wicket 7:

```
Wicket.Ajax.ajax({"u":"./page?6-2.IBehaviorListener.0-pageStyleClassWrapperPanel-choicePanel-content-choice","m":"POST","c":"choice3e","e":"change"});;
Wicket.Ajax.ajax({"u":"./page?6-2.IBehaviorListener.1-pageStyleClassWrapperPanel-choicePanel-content-choice","m":"POST","c":"choice3e","e":"blur"});;
```

We have similar issues also with other generated components like radiobuttons from icheck jquery lib.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks

Comment: clear of browser cache etc? I have only one (for me not important) ajax-problem by migration 6->7. First event of repeatable AjaxTimeoutBehaviour dont fire / is not visible that fire in FIrefox. Chrome seems ok. All the next look good, status displaying with % o realisation during database backup. Use in v. 7 few new ajaxified elements, very good

Comment: I just pulled the Wicket 7 quick start and implemented a dropdownchoice with the ajax behavior and it works flawless. maybe select 2 somehow blocks the event.

Comment: Clearing cache doesn't help, ajax behaviors don't work also on other computers and browsers. And as I said, problem is only with js generated components, ajax behaviors with default dropdown are working.

Comment: As a side node, there is a `Wicket` implementation for `select2` in `wicketstuff`

Comment: Do you have any js problems on that page? Look at the console of your browser. Javascript errors can halt all javascript execution on a page.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptom: Ajax behaviors did not work after migrating from Wicket 1.4 directly to Wicket 7.9.

In my case, the cause was: jquery javascript sources coudn't be loaded. They were being forbidden to be served.

My application used the class AuthStrategy, and it had a method:

```
@Override
public boolean isResourceAuthorized(IResource arg0, PageParameters arg1) {
    return false;
}
```

So, the jquery js sources couldnt be loaded. Changing the return to True solved the problem.

The only resources that seems to be passing thru that method are those jquery javascripts.